# Not seeing windows 10 when i trying to dualboot Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have a problem, I think? when trying to dual boot windows on a spearate hard drive. When i get to the installation menu I do not see the "Install Ubuntu alongside windows 10" and when i partion the drive in the "something else"-menu it do not recognice windows 10 on my C-drive.

Is this a problem? Im worried that if I install ubuntu on my F-drive I won't be able to access windows again.

Answer (score 0):

great question!

When installing Ubuntu (or it's derivatives) alongside Windows 10, as long as you don't change the existing EFI partition, or create a new one, (UEFI systems only), or destroy the Windows 10 boot loader/partition, you should be fine.

During install, Ubuntu looks for other supported operating systems, and their boot loaders. When Grub is installed during this process, it will automatically configure boot options for Ubuntu, and most (if not all) other operating systems, but will set Ubuntu as the default boot option.

All modern versions of Windows are considered supported, so with Windows 10, you should be perfectly fine.

I've installed Ubuntu, and Kubuntu alongside Windows 10 on MANY occasions in the last 3 years.

UEFI based BIOS also have the option of selecting which boot loader to run on startup. If you have this kind of system, you can always switch which boot loader runs by default (Windows, or Grub for Linux)

One thing to note is that Windows does not add Linux to it's list of operating systems to choose from on startup, so you will want to use Grub (Linux boot loader) if you want to be able to easily, and quickly switch your OS on boot.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, does Grub install automatically or is that something i have to install myself?

Comment: Grub is part of Ubuntu, so it gets installed automatically.